# Simple bit setting and cleaning

Tags: c++, algorithm, bitmap

I'm coding an exercise from a book. This program should set a "bitmapped graphics device" bits, and then check for any of them if they are 1 or 0. The setting function was already written so I only wrote the test_bit function, but it doesn't work.
In the main() I set the first byte's first bit to 1, so the byte is 10000000, then I want to test it: 10000000 & 10000000 == 10000000, so not null, but I still get false when I want to print it out. What's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

const int X_SIZE = 32;
const int Y_SIZE = 24;

char graphics[X_SIZE / 8][Y_SIZE];

inline void set_bit(const int x, const int y)
{
    graphics[(x)/8][y] |= (0x80 >> ((x)%8));
}

inline bool test_bit(const int x, const int y)
{
    return (graphics[x/8][y] & (0x80 >> ((x)%8)) != 0);
}

void print_graphics(void) //this function simulate the bitmapped graphics device
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int bit;

    for(y=0; y < Y_SIZE; y++)
    {
        for(x = 0; x < X_SIZE / 8; x++)
        {
            for(bit = 0x80;bit > 0; bit = (bit >> 1))
            {
                if((graphics[x][y] & bit) != 0)
                    std::cout << 'X';
                else
                    std::cout << '.';
            }
        }
    std::cout << '\n';
    }

}

main()
{
    int loc;

    for (loc = 0; loc < X_SIZE; loc++)
    {
        set_bit(loc,loc);
    }
    print_graphics();
    std::cout << "Bit(0,0): " << test_bit(0,0) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (x) return true else return false` is easier to read and write as `return x`.

Comment: It's also unnecessary to parenthesize the expression in a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MSVC++, I get a compiler warning ([C4554 'operator' : check operator precedence for possible error; use parentheses to clarify precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d2e57c5.aspx))

Add parentheses, and it works, like this:

```
inline bool test_bit(const int x, const int y)
{
    return ( ( graphics[x/8][y] & (0x80 >> ((x)%8)) ) != 0);
        //   ^                                      ^  Added parentheses
}
```

**Explanation**:
The problem is with order. The original line will first evalute `(0x80 >> ((x)%8) != 0`, which is `true`, or `1` as integer. and `0x80 & 0x01` then yields `0`, or `false` resp.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `0x80>>` not `1>>` in `test_bit`. Shifting one right tends to produce zero.

Also you need to write `(a & b) != 0`. The precedence of `==` and `!=` is higher than that of `&`, so `a & b != 0` is parsed as if it was written `a & (b != 0)`. (An old C / C++ gotcha.)

Comment: sorry, I changed it to 0x80 because I want to go right to left, but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: sorry, I mistyped it.